# Pivot Table Validation in YII

Tags: validation, yii, pivot-table

Sorry, I think I should re-describe the question:

I have three tables:

Posts (hold all posts)

Categories (hold categories for all posts)

Post_Categories (pivot table that holds relationship among Posts and Categories)

On Post form page, categories are displayed as Checkboxes. I need to make sure that user selects atleast one checkbox of categories. How do I achieve this?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I assume your categories value is an array, I wrote an [array validator for yii](http://code.google.com/p/phundament/source/browse/tags/2.1-b9/modules/p2/validators/P2ArrayValidator.php) once, maybe it does the job.
You should add the validator with attribute *'min'=>1* in your case.